# Detect Solidworks installation Release and service pack

Tags: solidworks

I'd want to detect installation of Solidworks to know release and Service Pack (if applied).
I have found one regisdtry key "install source" HKML / SOLIDWORK/Setup" but some computer have this key empty
Is there another way to get those informations ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified a language so I can't help you with the exact syntax, but using the SOLIDWORKS API, you can get the RevisionNumber method on the ISldWorks object.  According to the documentation:

> For all SOLIDWORKS executables prior to the initial public release of
>   SOLIDWORKS 2000, this method returns 1.0.0. For the initial public
>   release of SOLIDWORKS 2000, this method returns 8.0.0. For SOLIDWORKS
>   2000 SP1, this method returns 8.1.0, and each successive service pack
>   of SOLIDWORKS 2000 increments the leftmost decimal portion of the
>   return value. Each successive major public release increments the
>   portion of the return value to the left of the decimal point and the
>   initial public release of each has a decimal value of 0.0. For
>   example, the initial public release of SOLIDWORKS 2005 returns 13.0.0
>   whereas SOLIDWORKS 2005 SP0.1 returns 13.0.1 and SOLIDWORKS 2005 SP1
>   returns 13.1.0.
>
> Alpha, beta, and pre-release releases return negative minor revision
>   numbers:
>
> a1:    -1.0
>
> b1:    -2.0
>
> b2:    -3.0
>
> b3:    -4.0
>
> PR1:  -5.0 (This value might lower or higher depending on the number of beta releases.)
>
> For example, the return value for SOLIDWORKS 2015 beta2 was 23.-3.0.b1:

source:  [SOLIDWORKS ISldWorks.GetRevision() documentation](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks~solidworks.interop.sldworks.isldworks~revisionnumber.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;
using System;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        const string appString = "SldWorks.Application";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SldWorks swApp = null;

            try
            {
                swApp = (SldWorks)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(appString);
                if (swApp == null) throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(swApp));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                try
                {
                    swApp = (SldWorks)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(appString));
                    if (swApp == null) throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(swApp));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not get SolidWorks Version");
                }
            }

            if (swApp != null) Console.WriteLine("SolidWorks Version: {0}", swApp.RevisionNumber());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```